# How to add favicon to your wiki on mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, favicon

Is there any way to add favicon to your wiki pages created by mediawiki? As a Main/privileged user can i make changes on any page on wiki to get the favicon on all the pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `LocalSettings.php`, set [`$wgFavicon`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFavicon) to the path to the favicon file, i.e:

```
$wgFavicon = '/path/to/favicon.ico'
```

Alternately, naming your file `favicon.ico` at the site root will work, because `$wgFavicon` defaults to `/favicon.ico`.

These will only work if you have direct access to the server, so you can't do it from the MediaWiki interface.

Comment: Can i add clickable link images in sidebar using [[Mediawiki:Sidebar]],[[Mediawiki:common.css]],[[Mediawiki:Vector.css]]?   I was able to add images in the sidebar just using these three but cannot redirect them to some links.            [Click this link to see the preview of image in sidebar in mediawiki](https://imgur.com/tbtGjod) [Click this link to view the Mediawiki:Sidebar edit](https://imgur.com/a/CNE6DfD)                                                         [Click this link to view the Mediawiki:Vector.css edit](https://i.postimg.cc/fy9Yhfvm/wiki-stack-overflow-2.png)

Comment: @VenkateshGotimukul I suggest that you ask another question for that.

Comment: Actually the exact question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720686/how-to-add-image-with-link-in-a-sidebar-mediawiki) but i couldn't get the answer i need and thought it might be a duplicate of the same question that's the reason i didn't ask it as a separate question.